# Finding the Path in URL puzzle using Python

Tags: python, url

I'm given the Url which goes like this:

10.254.254.74 - - [06/Aug/2007:00:10:06 -0700] "GET /python/logpuzzle/p-bifb-baje.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 3341 "-" "googlebot-mscrawl-moma (enterprise; bar-XYZ; foo123@facebook.com,foo123@facebook.com,foo123@facebook.com,foo123@facebook.com)"

I'm tring to separate the Path, which start with the **Get** and ends with the **.jpg**.
There is any function that can do it for me or I have to code my own procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this whole thing is one big string, a ***very naive*** solution would be a regex that simply grabs whatever is between `GET` and `HTTP`:

```
import re

string = '''10.254.254.74 - - [06/Aug/2007:00:10:06 -0700] "GET /python/logpuzzle/p-bifb-baje.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 3341 "-" "googlebot-mscrawl-moma (enterprise; bar-XYZ; foo123@facebook.com,foo123@facebook.com,foo123@facebook.com,foo123@facebook.com)"'''

try:
    print(re.findall(r'GET(.+)HTTP', string)[0].strip())
except IndexError:
    print('Nothing was found')

# /python/logpuzzle/p-bifb-baje.jpg
```

The used regex can get as complicated as necessery, for example by introducing a lookbehind and lookahead depending on the expected structure of the input.